# PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: ssl, wso2, paas

I was trying to intall the WSO2 Private PaaS 4.0.0 on HP Helion Public Cloud (formerly HP Cloud). the install finished withe following errors

```
Starting WSO2 IS core service...
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
Restoring from the Original template file /home/ubuntu/paas/resources/json/os/partition.json
Deploying partition at /home/ubuntu/paas/resources/json/os/partition.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Invalid Partition Detected : P1. Cause: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target connecting to POST https://region-a.geo-1.identity.hpcloudsvc.com:35357/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1"}}Deploying autoscale policy at /home/ubuntu/paas/resources/json/os/autoscale-policy.json
{"stratosAdminResponse":{"message":"Successfully deployed autoscaling policy definition with id economy"}}Deploying deployment policy at /home/ubuntu/paas/resources/json/os/deployment-policy.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Deployment policy is invalid: [id] deployp"}}Deploying deployment policy at /home/ubuntu/paas/resources/json/os/deployment-flat.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Deployment policy is invalid: [id] deployf"}}Deploying LB cartridge at /home/ubuntu/paas/resources/json/os/lb-cart.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: openstack"}}Deploying Aplication Server (AS) cartridge at /home/ubuntu/paas/resources/json/os/appserver-cart.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: openstack"}}Deploying Application Service service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] appserver [alias] b25aa290-4d15-4160-ab29-3fb65450a50c . Cause: appserver is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}Deploying Business Process Server (BPS) cartridge at /home/ubuntu/paas/resources/json/os/bps-cart.json
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Unable to build the jclouds object for iaas of type: openstack"}}Deploying Business Process Server service
{"Error":{ "errorCode": " 400", "errorMessage": " Failed to deploy the Service [Cartridge type] bps [alias] 9f8501bd-2707-41b8-8169-575f76e80e74 . Cause: bps is not a valid cartridgeSubscription type. Please try again with a valid cartridgeSubscription type."}}
```

the conf.sh

```
# IaaS configuration
export iaas="os"
# Region Name
export region="region-a.geo-1"
# Cartridge base image
export cartridge_base_img_id="xxxxxxxa2-bff1-41cf-8f92-c3xxxxxxx5b"

# OpenStack
export os_identity="1XXXXXXXXXX:XXXXX5BL7VXXXXXXXXX"
export os_credentials="AMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
export os_jclouds_endpoint="https://region-a.geo-1.identity.hpcloudsvc.com:35357/v2.0/"
export os_keypair_name="xxxxxx"
export os_security_groups="xxxxxxx"
```

I googled around and found out that the reason of problems be that certificate of the jcloud endpoint (https://region-a.geo-1.identity.hpcloudsvc.com:35357/v2.0) can not be found by the PaaS.

I first tried to import the endpoint certificate to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts using the keytool -import -keystore command. is does not work and the same problems persists

I then tried to import the endpoint certificate to /home/ubuntu/.keystore. the same problem stil persists.

please advise

thanks

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cetifacte of the backend (jclouds endpoint) should be added to the WSO2 Private PaaS's client-truststore.jks. Have a look at [1]

[1] http://evanthika.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-solve-pkix-path-building-failed.html

Comment: there are actually to keystore client-truststore.jks and wso2carbon.jks

Comment: here are actually to keystore client-truststore.jks and wso2carbon.jks. I am actually not  working with ESB but PaaS, I am not sure which to use. so I added to both keystores the jcloud endpoint certification. I would say it works, yet I cannot be sure which one did the tricks ...

Comment: You should only add jclouds endpoint's certificate to WSO2 Private PaaS's client-truststore.jks. Don't need to add it to wso2carbon.jks.